# Hibernate manytomany @JoinTable + @SecondaryTable duplicate entries

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a relation of type `@ManyToMany` with a `@JoinTable` association.

The thing is that the entity in the relation has its own table, but a couple of properties should go to the association table.

The `A_C` table is fine I think.

Adding the `@SecondaryTable` duplicate.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@SecondaryTable(name = "A_C", pkJoinColumns = {
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(columnDefinition = "A_ID", name = "A_ID")})
class A {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")})
    private List<B> bs = new ArrayList<B>();

    @Column(table = "A_B")
    private int b1;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@SecondaryTable(name = "A_B", pkJoinColumns = {
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(columnDefinition = "B_ID", name = "B_ID")})
class B {
    @Column(table = "A_B")
    private int a1;

    @Column(table = "A_B")
    private int a2;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "A_ID", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<A> as = new ArrayList<A>();

}
```

This when saving `A` entities the `B` are duplicated in a way where:

```
A_ID    B_ID   a1     a2
   1       0    1      1    
   1       1    0      0
```

Where should be

```
A_ID    B_ID   a1    a2
   1       1    1     1
```

With `@Embeddable` won't work neither.

ssedano.

Answer (score 0):

`A_B` is the Join-Table for Table `A` and `B` but you're also using it as a secondary table for `B`.

This doesn't work. What values should `B.a1` and `B.a2` have if a `B` is assigned to multiple `A`s?

There are three possibilities:
* a1 and a2 are belong to the association. In that case you need a association class, which stores that additional information.
* a1 and a2 only belong to B: a1 and a2 should not be in table `A_B`
* `A` is a composition of `B`: Table `A_B` and `B` should be merged and the many-to-many relationship replaced by an one-to-many relationship.

Without specific names for the attributes it's hard to tell were they actually belong.